# AWS: How to find I am connected to Ephemeral Storage, Object Storage or Block Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, openstack, openstack-swift, aws-opsworks

Is it recommended to create SWAP on Ephemeral Disk, is it true?

How to make sure how many types of storage are connected to AWS Instance having only SSH access?

How would I make sure, I am accessing Ephemeral disk, Object Storage or Block storage? Or how to switch between different types of storage (i.e. Ephemeral, Object and Block)?

Is it possible that I can fire `fdsisk` command on particular kind of storage disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SWAP on Ephemeral Disk

- True . This is because otherwise you're essentially sending your CPU to do a query into the network based EBS volume for the data.

## use the curl command

```
~  curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/
ami
ephemeral0
root% 

curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral0
sdb%
```

## switching

Object Storage is the aws-s3 service. It's accessed via the aws-sdk OR via their api.

## fdisk

will show both the EBS and Ephemeral as std disk. Equivalent of how normal san volumes show up on a linux box. You can parse the output from the the key value store to determine where the likely mount points are supposed to be.

Comment: Hi Imran! Thanks for your reply! I have tried to fire `curl` on m1.micro aws instance but it shows me only ebs2 storage it has. Does it mean that for small instance (i.e. CentOS 6.5 Free instance doesn't have ephemeral disk)?

Comment: those micro instances have nothing other than their root partition, which is the ebs volume by default.

Comment: Thanks Imran Ahmed :)